# Java - остановить дочерний поток на некоторое время

Tags: java, многопоточность, sleep

Я знаю, что можно остановить текущий поток с помощью Thread.sleep() , можно ли как-нибудь остановить дочерний поток?

Comment: приведите пример кода, как создаётся дочерний поток и в каком месте вы хотите его остановить.

Answer (score 1):

Есть метод `Thread.suspend()` но он объявлен устаревшим и крайне не рекомендован к использованию из-за возможности появления дедлоков при засыпании после захвата, но до освобождения ресурсов.

Лучшее решение, это когда поток периодически сам проверяет некий флаг "а не пора ли мне заснуть?"

Answer (score 0):

Поток должен самостоятельно управлять собственным жизненным циклом. Другой поток может только отправлять ему сигналы, изменяя общее состояние:

```
public class Example {
    public static volatile boolean run = true;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (run) {  // Пока run == true
                // Поток делает свои дела
            }
        }).start();

        // Главный поток устанавливает новое значение общей
        // переменной и этим останавливает другой поток
        run = false;
    }
}
```